# How to change currency on webpage if my currency not available on the website?

Tags: windows-7, browser, browser-addons, currency-format

For example this in an Indian website http://compareindia.in.com/products/monitors/

All prices on page are in INR (currency of India), is there any plugin/add-on on any browser which can change the curreny of page INR to any: USD, AUD, GBP etc?

Comment: Learn the currency names. Then google `10000 inr in usd`.

Comment: I know about google I want to change the currency at all places on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that would 'allow' you to change foreign webpages to your style, is to get Grease Monkey (firefox plugin) it allows YOU the user to customize content on other websites (just for yourself tho, keep that in mind, nobody else will see these changes).

Wiki entry:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey

Official site:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/
- http://userscripts.org/

List of Currency conversion scripts:

- http://userscripts.org/search?cref=http%3A%2F%2Fuserscripts.org%2Fcse.xml&cof=FORID%3A9&q=currency&x=0&y=0#906

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [Chrome Currency Converter](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/anbfhidldjknonaihbalghlebaijealk) is what you need.

If you're on Mozilla Firefox, look at [Forex Converter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/forex-currency-converter/)